# PresentationMode triggers "Variable X used before being initialized"

Tags: swiftui

[image: Error messages]
I'm trying to write a reusable quick select field editor for a SwiftUI application. The code below only shows the error `Variable 'self.fieldValue' used before initialized` if the `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>` is present. If I remove that, the view compiles fine. Anyone know why the presentationmode environment variable is causing this and how to fix it? I need the presentationmode env var so I can quickly pop the view once the user clicks on a button.

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

@State var viewName = "Edit Field"
@Binding var fieldValue: Int
@State var fieldName: String = ""
var options: [Int]

init(title: String, field: String, value: Binding<Int>, list: [Int]) {
    viewName = title
    fieldName = field
    _fieldValue = value
    options = list
}
```

For full view code, see below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CommonNumberEditView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    @State var viewName = "Edit Field"
    @Binding var fieldValue: Int
    @State var fieldName: String = ""
    var options: [Int]
    
    init(title: String, field: String, value: Binding<Int>, list: [Int]) {
        viewName = title
        fieldName = field
        _fieldValue = value
        options = list
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("sky")
                .resizable()
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .opacity(0.5)
            
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5)
            {
                JumpLogNumberField(label: self.fieldName, val: self.$fieldValue)
                
                ScrollView {
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                        ForEach(options, id: \.self) { item in
                            Group {
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                                }) {
                                    Text(String(item))
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .padding(20)
                                }
                                .frame(minWidth:0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.6))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            }
            .padding(.top, 40)
            .padding(.leading, 40)
            .padding(.trailing, 40)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
        }.navigationBarTitle(viewName, displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct CommonFieldEditView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        CommonNumberEditView(title: "Edit Field", field: "Altitude", value: .constant(5000), list: [ 13500, 10000, 5500, 3500 ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is fixed part of code:

```
struct CommonNumberEditView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    @State private var viewName: String
    @Binding var fieldValue: Int
    @State private var fieldName: String
    var options: [Int]

    init(title: String, field: String, value: Binding<Int>, list: [Int]) {
        _viewName = State(initialValue: title)
        _fieldName = State(initialValue: field)
        _fieldValue = value
        options = list
    }

// ...
```

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

Comment: This is such a weird problem, with a weird error message, and a weird fix. Works though...

Comment: @teynon: It was not weird problem! You JUST did not respect to the syntax of initialization of State or Binding! Also not a weird fix! it is pretty normal! How ever putting your own initiation is not recommended in general.

Comment: @swiftPunk It's weird because the side affect and error message have nothing to do with the actual problem. The error doesn't happen at all if the completely unrelated `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>` is removed. The error message complains about a different variable than the text it's highlighting in the picture. There is nothing intuitive about this error message or the method of solving it. I would argue that makes it pretty weird. Seems like a bug in XCode to me.

Comment: @teynon: As I said it was nothing weird, everyone that knows how can initialization of State or Binding done, would not call it weird for 120% sure!, but it is indeed weird that you call the issue was or is weird! :)

Comment: @swiftPunk If it's not weird, can you explain why the above code works if I remove the `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>`?

Comment: @teynon: Your code at your question has initialization syntax issue in first place, if even SwiftUI could build that code(which I do not believe)! I would say you were lucky or we could call it weird success build with wrong syntax! I see your codes in your question, you literally initialized `viewName` with `Edit Field` and then you where trying initialize it again in an init() again? Who do this thing? or who make this big mistake in coding? I believe your issue is much more deeper than initialization of State or Binding, you need to educate yourself about initialization in Swift in general!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236920/discussion-between-teynon-and-swiftpunk).

Answer (score 1):

## Warning

You should not initialize State variables in your View's init because that can cause problems with how SwiftUI works and updates.

By creating a new State variable each time a new instance of your struct is created you don't get the benefit of `@State` sharing the value across all instances of your struct when the parent view is re-rendered/updates.

For example if you are putting those `@State` values in TextFields every time the parent view is reloaded/updated (e.g. because the `@Binding` changes) it will create a new subview that resets them to the initial values.

---

You can initialize a `@Binding` in init because the value is coming from somewhere else so it doesn't matter if it gets overwritten, it will have the same source of truth, and thus same value.

## Solution

In your view you aren't changing the values of `viewName` or `fieldName` so you don't need to use `@State`. You can just remove `@State` from `viewName` and `fieldName`, and everything should still work as you expect, just with a cleaner init.

If you do need them to be editable you should convert them into @Binding, just like the `fieldValue` is so that they update whatever is actually storing the value.

Comment: That is true that every time the view would get rendered when he change the value of `viewName` or `fieldName`, in this case he could even use `let` without any wrapper, but maybe he is going update `viewName` or `fieldName` inside the body after initialization! then updating those would not force view to re-initialization, it will still make the view get calculated and rendered because we updated a State, but it would not make to re-initialization happen! PS: the view would get initialized with updating those values in body! but State would not get initialized, because of: State(initialValue)

Comment: When a view is re-rendered a new instance is created to compare against the existing instance. So anything that causes the view to be re-rendered (change in @State, @ObservedObject, @Binding, etc) will cause a new instance to be initialized. When you use `@State` (without manually initializing it in `init`) SwiftUI automatically reuses the value from the existing instance, if you manually initialize the `@State` variable in init you override that.
As I mentioned in my answer if they need to edit the values they should be `@Binding` (because the view doesn't own the values).

Comment: I tested this a little more and realized that more accurately the body is re-computed, which means that any views that are created in that view's body are re-initialized for the comparison. So you are right that a view isn't necessarily reinitialized for the comparison. I'll update my answer to be clearer on what I meant.